# Can we use Facebook API in modern java batch?

Tags: java, facebook, java-batch

Can we use Facebook API in modern java batch?
Need some information like is that possible to use that API in modern java batch, if so how can we implement it?

Comment: Basically all you need to be able to make API requests is the ability to make HTTP(S) requests ...

Comment: Yes is the answer to the first question. For the rest of your questions you'll actually have to do some work for

Answer (score 0):

The below link shows all the instructions of using Facebook API in java, not from the official site, but this works so far. Just Add facebook4j-core-2.4.8.jar to your application classpath.

http://facebook4j.github.io/en/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the info.